# One header but with different banners for each page (php if)

Tags: php, html, if-statement, header, banner

I build my website for fun and want to put different banner on each page, in my header i have random banners who appear with this code,

```
<div style=' height:145px; background-image:url(images/banners/banner<?php 
echo rand(1,3); ?>.jpg); background-position:center center; border-
radius:4px;'></div>
```

So there is 3 banners and each time i refresh random one appear, but i want to have another 3 banners for my other page but with the same include"inc/header.php", maybe 'if' statement could work but i really don't know how to do it. 
Sorry for my English i'm french.

Comment: Are the other 3 banners in the same folder, or somewhere else?

Comment: In the same folder, my folder is just named banners

Comment: add remaining 3 images to the same folder

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the three banners are in the same folder, the following would be a simple solution:

Place the banner code in a separate file:

banner.php

```
    <div style=' height:145px; background-image:url(images/banners/banner<?php 
echo rand($start,$end); ?>.jpg); background-position:center center; border-
radius:4px;'></div>
```

Then you can call it from your page:

```
$start = 4;  //First banner number
$end = 6;    //Last banner number
include('inc/banner.php');
```

This is not the most elegant solution, but it's a simple nice simple one for a novice programmer that introduces some concepts.

Comment: It works but i have only one header so the start = 4 end = 6 will be for all pages , i only need specific range for every page in my website

Comment: You can set start and end at any point before you load the banner. Just place that piece of code in the page itself (in `<?php ?>` closures ) and you're good!

Answer (score 0):

I found how to do it myself:

```
<?php if ($title == "page1"): ?>
<div style=' height:145px; background-image:url(images/banners/banner<?
php echo rand(1,6); ?>.jpg); background-position:center center; border-
radius:4px;'></div>

<?php elseif ($title == "page2"): ?>
<div style=' height:145px; background-image:url(images/banners/banner<?php 
echo rand(7,9); ?>.jpg); background-position:center center; border-
radius:4px;'></div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

I just need to create new "elseif" for every page and assign new banners with the same header.php all over my website.

Answer (score -1):

```
use if
example
if ($id == 1){
   <div style=' height:145px; background-image:url(images/banners/banner<?
      php 
          echo rand(1,3); ?>.jpg); background-position:center center; 
    border-
               radius:4px;'></div>
      }
             if ($id == 2){
         <div style=' height:145px; background-
      image:url(images/banners/banner<?php 
     echo rand(1,3); ?>.jpg); background-position:center center; border-
   radius:4px;'></div>
      }
    if ($id == 3){
         echo "no banner";
              }
```

help fixing this sh!t mod, thanks

Comment: This won't compile, and if that were fixed, it would show the same banners every time!

Comment: This doesn't work good, exemple again for what i want: 1st page have banners 1 2 and 3, my 2nd page have banners 4,5,6 and all that with the same header who i include in every start of my web pages